# rails missing template from link_to and send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display the contents of a Log file, a txt file in html.
I get 'Template missing error'.

```
Missing template application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/Documents/workspace/demo2/app/views"
```

In my controller I have

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
  def displaycontents
  send_file "/home/Documents/workspace/demo.txt", 
          :type => "text/html", 
          :disposition => 'inline'
  end
 end
```

In my routes.rb I have

```
root 'application#index'
```

In my index.html.erb I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>new view</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%= link_to "Log File", :controller=> :application,
    :action=>:displaycontents %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have kept the index action in the controller file empty so the index.html.erb is rendered by default.

I have restarted the rails server as suggested by another solution.
And the index.html.erb file is present in demo2/app/views .

The different verions I have used are
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 
-Rails : 4.0.2

Comment: *demo2/app/views*? The template should be placed under *demo2/app/views/application*. Can you give it a try?

Comment: When do you get this error? when you go to `localhost:3000` or when you click on the link?

Answer (score 1):

Add `and return` after send_file in order to avoid rendering view.

```
send_file("/home/Documents/workspace/demo.txt", :type => "text/html", :disposition => 'inline') and return
```